# How to count list occurrences with a Data.Map?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there a way to use `Data.Map` in Haskell to find the number of occurrences in a given list, be it a character or an integer?
For example: `[Int] -> Map Int Int`.

If it's possible to achieve, would you be able to do it without the use of `fromList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a `Map k Int` that acts as a counter for the items in a list with [**`fromListWith :: (Hashable k, Ord k) => (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map k a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.3.3/docs/Data-HashMap.html#v:fromListWith). We can implement such function as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Data.Hashable(Hashable)
import Data.HashMap(Map, fromListWith)

toCounter :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => [a] -> Map a Int
toCounter = fromListWith (+) . map (,1)
```

Here we convert each element to a 2-tuple with `1` as the second item of the 2-tuple. In case there is a clash between two keys, we resolve this by summing up the number of times that item occurred.

This produces for example:

```
ghci> toCounter [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
fromList [(0,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1)]
```

here for the list `[1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]` `0`, `3`, `4` and `5` occur once, and `1` and `2` occur twice.

> If it's possible to achieve, would you be able to do it without the use of `fromList`?

Yes, you can work with [**`foldl' :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-) and [**`insertWith :: (Hashable k, Ord k) => (a -> a -> a) -> k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.3.3/docs/Data-HashMap.html#v:insertWith) . I leave it as an exercise to convert the `toCounter` function to a *fold pattern*.